# Implementation of ApplicationCommands.Copy in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, command

I just created a menu with `Command = "ApplicationCommands.Copy"` and I thought I had to handle the `Executed` event of the binding, and add a binding but I just don't need to.

Now I'm confused!

Where is the implementation of this command? How can it automatically copy a text selected in any of the textboxes I have in my window?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How did you verify that you didn't need to handle the `Executed` event of the command - was it with the built-in `TextBox`? If so, the reason that you don't have to handle it is because the `TextBox` handles that command already (since it is built-in). The same is true for the other edit commands - Cut, Paste, Undo, Redo (and probably others as well).

If you were using your own custom command, then you would need to handle its `Executed` event, as you stated in your question.